# ASP.NET link works in development but not in production

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get a link on a web page working. It works fine when I run the in visual studio. When I release it (in docker compose), I get the equivalent of a page not found error.

I am using .NET CORE 3.1, my controller looks like this

```
    [Route("Home/ViewTeams")]
    public ActionResult ViewTeams()
    {
        TeamData
            = new TeamDataFacade(
                MongoClient.GetCollection<Team>(),
                MongoClient);

        List<Team> teams = TeamData.GetDocuments();
        return View(teams);
    }
```

Code for the link

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Teams","ViewTeams","Home")
```

I have looks at various web pages, tried a few variations. Even asked a few people. We suspect there is a problem with the setup of the project, or something missing.

Running in the development IDE (Visual Studio 2019) it works. In the released docker environment. I get the following.

[image: Error]

However in my Docker file it specifies Release mode

```
RUN dotnet build "Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just wondering if it's as simple as missing a nuget package maybe?

Comment: I installed AttributeRouting (Install-Package AttributeRouting -Version 3.4.2) problem persists. If I find the solution I will post it here, but if anyone knows the answer, I would really appreciate the help :-)